# Google Maps API: Randomized street view

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have been working on some code with the google maps API. I'm trying to get a randomized street view location.

First I get a randomized location and look for a possible panorama in the area, once It gets the "OK" I tried to take the location data and create a panorama with it. I expected it to generate a new panorama but I just got a black screen and when I console.logged the data.latlng I got undefined. I also had no errors in the console

```
    function generateRandomPoint()
    {
        var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
        sv.getPanoramaByLocation(
            new google.maps.LatLng(Math.random()*180 - 90,Math.random()*360 - 180), 500,processSVData
            );
    }
    
    function processSVData(data, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
            console.log("EE");
            
            const panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById("panoramamap"),
                {
                    position: data.latLng,
                        pov: {
                            heading: 34,
                            pitch: 10,
                    },
                    disableDefaultUI: true,
                }
            );
            
      } else generateRandomPoint();
    }
      
      window.onload = function() {
        generateRandomPoint();
        console.log("E");
      }
```

Comment: Where did your code come from?  I don't see `.latLng` in the [`StreetViewResponse`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/street-view-service#StreetViewResponse) object (so I would expect it to be undefined).

Answer (score 0):

Related question: [Change google maps street view position dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63398031/change-google-maps-street-view-position-dynamically)

Not sure where your code came from.  `data.latLng` doesn't exist in the [`StreetViewResponse`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/street-view-service#StreetViewResponse) object, so I would expect it to be undefined.

What does exist is `.location` which is a [`StreetViewLocation`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/street-view-service#StreetViewLocation) object, which does contain a `latLng` property which is a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng) object.

This code works for me (although you may want to consider not hammering Google's StreetViewService with random locations covering the whole world):

```
function processSVData(data, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
    console.log("EE");
            
    const panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById("panoramamap"),
    {
      position: data.location.latLng,
      pov: {
        heading: 34,
        pitch: 10,
      },
      disableDefaultUI: true,
    });
            
  } else generateRandomPoint();
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kcpmsx1h/)

[image: screenshot of result with working StreetView panorama]

**code snippet:**

```js
function generateRandomPoint() {
  var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
  sv.getPanoramaByLocation(
    new google.maps.LatLng(Math.random() * 180 - 90, Math.random() * 360 - 180), 500, processSVData
  );
}

function processSVData(data, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
    console.log("EE " + data.location.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
    console.log(data);

    const panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById("panoramamap"), {
        position: data.location.latLng,
        pov: {
          heading: 34,
          pitch: 10,
        },
        disableDefaultUI: true,
      }
    );

  } else generateRandomPoint();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#panoramamap {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Street View Containers</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="panoramamap"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=generateRandomPoint&libraries=&v=weekly" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```